# git log --follow -L280,+20:foo.c --> git logs can only follow renames on one pathname at a time

Tags: git, rename

I try to see the changes of a part of a file beyond renames:

```
git log --follow -L280,+20:foo.c
```

I get this error message:

```
usage: git logs can only follow renames on one pathname at a time
```

I use git version 1.9.1

How to see the changes of a part of a file, even if the file was renamed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is mainly a problem of the error-message in older git versions. With git 2.4.1 i get the following error-message:

```sh
$ git log --follow -L280,+20:foo.c
fatal: --follow requires exactly one pathspec
```

While only slightly better this message lead me to try the following (which works):

```sh
$ git log --follow -L280,+20:foo.c -- foo.c
```

The problem seems to be that `-L280,+20:foo.c` only restricts the line range, but doesn't provide the `pathspec` which is necessary for `--follow`.